# SQL select query to return only 1 row base on specific criteria from child table

Tags: sql, oracle

I cannot work out to how return specific parent data row/s depending on what values exist in the child table.

There is two filters or some case statement where I want to apply which returns me the `registration_id` from `table1` depending on the values in the child table.

1. Return the `regestration_id` when `Table3` has `type` values of both `1` and `3`. In this case, it should return `registration_id` of `123`.
2. Return the `regestration_id` when `Table3` has only `type` value of `1` and `type` of `3` does not exist. In this case, it should return `registration_id` of `321`.

This is the SQL I have used to join the tables:

```
select registration_id from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t2.registration_id=t1.registration_id 
left join table3 t3 on t3.x_person_id=t2.x_person_id;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `EXISTS`:

```sql
select t1.registration_id
from   table1 t1 
       inner join table2 t2
       on t2.registration_id=t1.registration_id
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   table3 t3
         WHERE  t3.type = 1
         AND    t3.x_person_id = t2.x_person_id
       )
AND    EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   table3 t3
         WHERE  t3.type = 3
         AND    t3.x_person_id = t2.x_person_id
       );
```

and `NOT EXISTS`:

```sql
select t1.registration_id
from   table1 t1 
       inner join table2 t2
       on t2.registration_id=t1.registration_id
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   table3 t3
         WHERE  t3.type = 1
         AND    t3.x_person_id = t2.x_person_id
       )
AND    NOT EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   table3 t3
         WHERE  t3.type = 3
         AND    t3.x_person_id = t2.x_person_id
       );
```

---

If you want to do it in one `EXISTS` then:

```sql
select t1.registration_id
from   table1 t1 
       inner join table2 t2
       on t2.registration_id=t1.registration_id
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   table3 t3
         WHERE  t3.type IN (1, 3)
         AND    t3.x_person_id = t2.x_person_id
         HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t3.type) = 2
       )
```

and:

```sql
select t1.registration_id
from   table1 t1 
       inner join table2 t2
       on t2.registration_id=t1.registration_id
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   table3 t3
         WHERE  t3.type IN (1, 3)
         AND    t3.x_person_id = t2.x_person_id
         HAVING COUNT(CASE t3.type WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) > 0
         AND    COUNT(CASE t3.type WHEN 3 THEN 1 END) = 0
       )
```

Comment: That was super useful! and I learn a lot about the EXISTS function. Ran this in the DB however due to my incorrect presentation of the table data, the sql is not working. The column x_person_id is unqiue unfortunately... so the exists value 1 + exists value 3 will not work and return 0 rows.